# Youtube reporting API returns 403 for content owner reports

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, youtube-analytics-api

I am trying to download content owner reports via the [Youtube Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/). When I try to list reports by content owner (onBehalfOfContentOwner) I get a 403 `"The caller does not have permission"`. When I leave out the content owner parameter I only get channel reports back.

I have tried using OAuth2 tokens generated for both a manager of the channel and the channel user itself ([generated using the server-side flow:](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization/server-side-web-apps)). This happens from both the client library and the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/reportTypes/list).

What could be going wrong here? Perhaps the issue has to do with the way the accounts are set up in Google Cloud - the channel manager has been added to the Google Cloud project, and the Youtube Reporting and Youtube Analytics have been enabled for that project.

Comment: There must be agreement between the account with which you authenticate, and the CONTENT_OWNER_ID you provide.

Comment: Is that different from authenticating as the channel owner?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into the same issue and desperate for any insight!